# Make a while loop when the array is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have code that will make an array or arrays of UNKNOWN length because it depends on how many new people have been added to the mysql DB. (this is where I'm getting confused)

The array has $x items, each item is an array of first name, last name, and e-mail address.

I want the loop to run till the array is ended.

```
$x = 0;
while($array[$x]['per_LastName'] != 'NULL') {
    $batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$array[$x]['per_Email'], 'FNAME'=>$array[$x]['per_FirstName'], 'LNAME'=>$array[$x]['per_LastName']);
    $x = $x+1;
    }
```

apparently I'm looping infinity because it uses all the memory.

Comment: Why not use a `foreach` here?  `foreach($array as $val){ $val['per_LastName'] }`

Comment: For what it's worth, your loop is currently looping infinitely because you're comparing with `'NULL'`. The single quotes mean that this is a string, which contains the word NULL, which is different from an actual NULL value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop which will loop through all elements of the array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$value['per_Email'], 'FNAME'=>$value['per_FirstName'], 'LNAME'=>$value['per_LastName']);
}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks.    Can you elaborate on the way this works or link me something. I searched a lot but didn't see a way to do this.

Comment: A `foreach` loop goes through each element of the array `$array` and runs the loop for each one. The `$key => $value` means that they key of the array element will be stored in `$key` and its value in `$value`. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you should use a `for` loop

```
for($x = 0; $x<count($array); $x++){
    $batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$array[$x]['per_Email'], 'FNAME'=>$array[$x]['per_FirstName'], 'LNAME'=>$array[$x]['per_LastName']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use foreach and avoid counters and unnecessary checks?

```
foreach($array as $eachArray)
{
    $batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$eachArray['per_Email'], 'FNAME'=>$eachArray['per_FirstName'], 'LNAME'=>$eachArray['per_LastName']);
    }
```